# Django loop in html issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i had been trying to solve this problem for almost  3 hrs but i didnt get the result i want,

this is the result i want

[image]

this is my current result

[image]

this is my html

```
 <table  id="blacklistgrid" border="2px">
     <tr>
         <th>Students Name</th>
         {% for student in teacherStudents %}<th >{{student.Date}}</th>{% endfor %}
         <th data-id='headers' id='headerave'>Average</th>
                 </tr>
     <tr>
    <tbody id="scoreboard">
    {% for students in studentname %}
    <tr class="tr2">
        <td><input type="text" name="students" value="{{student.id}}" id="student" hidden>{{students.Students_Enrollment_Records.Students_Enrollment_Records.Student_Users}}</td>
     <tr>
      {% endfor %}
     </tr>
      <tr>
          {% for studentss in Students %}
           <td class="td" scope="row"><input type="text" name="students" value="{{student.id}}" id="student" hidden>{{studentss.Grade}}</td>{% endfor %}
           <td data-id='row' id="ans"><input type='number' class='averages' step="any" name="average" readonly/></td>
       </tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>
```

this is my views.py

```
teacherStudents = studentsEnrolledSubjectsGrade.objects.filter(Teacher = teacher).filter(grading_Period = period).filter(Subjects = subject).filter(Grading_Categories = category).filter(GradeLevel = grade).distinct('Date')
studentname = studentsEnrolledSubjectsGrade.objects.filter(Teacher = teacher).filter(grading_Period = period).filter(Subjects = subject).filter(Grading_Categories = category).filter(GradeLevel = grade).distinct('Students_Enrollment_Records')
Students = studentsEnrolledSubjectsGrade.objects.filter(Teacher = teacher).filter(grading_Period = period).filter(Subjects = subject).filter(Grading_Categories = category).filter(GradeLevel = grade)
return render(request, 'Homepage/period.html',{"teacherStudents":teacherStudents,"Students":Students,"studentname":studentname})
```

my models.py

```
class studentsEnrolledSubjectsGrade(models.Model):
    Teacher = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                null=True,blank=True)
    GradeLevel = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                null=True,blank=True)
    Subjects = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrolledSubject, related_name='+',
                                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Grading_Categories = models.ForeignKey(gradingCategories, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                null=True,blank=True)
    grading_Period = models.ForeignKey(gradingPeriod, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                null=True,blank=True)
    #Items = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    Grade = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

this is my data in admin.py

[image]

can you guys help me in my html loop? do you have suggestions? my database is postgresql

UPDATE just like mr @Chris said in the comment section, I want to create a table with a row per student and in the columns the grades at a specific date, **Create the table in your view (e.g. as a list of lists or one annotated queryset) and use the template for rendering** but i dont know how, please help me guys,

Comment: Please post your complete html template (at least the complete part for rendering the table). Looking at the fragment you posted it seems your table tags are going wild and all over the place

Comment: okay wait sir...

Comment: please see my update question

Comment: One more question. Is there any reason why you are sending three querysets to you template?

Comment: yes, because i have to distinct the date, Students name just look at my admin.py data, i just posted it

Comment: as you can see, i have 2 dates, 8 students name that is why i use distinct

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to create a table with a row per student and in the columns the grades at a specific date. With your current approach you need to coordinate 3 querysets in you template (e.g. to place a grade value into the correct row and column). IMHO do not try to do that. Create the table in your view (e.g. as a list of lists or one annotated queryset) and use the template for rendering.

Comment: can you help me to create table inside views? this is new to me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208334/discussion-between-kaito-and-chris).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest generating the table in your view and the pass it to your template for rendering.

```
#views.py

def your_view(request):

    students = StudentsEnrolledSubjectsGrade.objects.filter(put_in_your_filters).order_by('student_name', 'date').values('student_name', 'date', 'grade')
    dates = list(students.values_list('date', flat=True).distinct().order_by('date'))

    # table basics
    table = []
    student_name = None
    table_row = None
    columns = len(dates) + 1

    # table header
    table_header = ['Student Name']
    table_header.extend(dates)
    table.append(table_header)

    for student in students:
        if not student['student_name'] == student_name:
            if not table_row is None:
                table.append(table_row)
            table_row = [None for d in range(columns)]
            student_name = student['student_name'] 
            table_row[0] = student_name

        table_row[dates.index(student['date']) + 1] = student['grade']

    table.append(table_row)

    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'table': table})
```

Then you can interate through all the rows of that table in you template:

```
<table  id="blacklistgrid" border="2px">
    <tr>
        {% for v in table.0 %}
        <td>{{ v }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>

    <tbody>
    {% for row in table|slice:"1:" %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.0 }}</td>
            {% for c in row|slice:"1:" %}
            <td>{{ c }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
     {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
</table>
```

You need to adapt that to your needs, it is just to give you an idea

Comment: i get this error """django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: slice requires 2 arguments, 1 provided"""

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo near the second "slice" - I missed the ```:``` directly after slice. Corrected that

Comment: mr @Chris please see this question , ipost another question same like this , i copy your answer,   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60359061/django-table-in-view please help